# Widget timer, SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget

I have the following configuration for my widget:

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SimpleEntry>) -> Void) {
   var currentDate: Date = Date()
   let entry = SimpleEntry(date: currentDate.addingTimeInterval(60))
   let timeline: Timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .atEnd)
   completion(timeline)
}
```

I would love to have a timer COUNTING UP, given a certain amount of seconds. (Let's say the timer should start from 120 seconds, so it goes: 2:00, 2:01, 2:02 and so on).

The main problem here is that the timer is always COUNTING DOWN.

This is the swiftUI view:

```
Text(entry.date, style: .timer)
```

How can I achieve the desired result? Is the reload policy correct?

Comment: Look at `TimelineView`

Comment: are there any other solutions that doesnt require ios15+?

Comment: Manually creating all the entries in advance on `getTimeline`

Comment: I believe that your answers are not helping at all. Im experimenting with Timelineview, Text(... style: .timer) etc.. But still not getting the desired result. Could you provide a working sample?

Comment: With timeline view I can't use Text(... style: .seconds) to show a live timer. Seconds are only showed once in a while

Comment: Maybe I'm asking a question with attached sample to share with other the implementation and to be useful for the community